# How to deploy your MonoDroid app to phone

Tags: c#, android, deployment, xamarin.android

I have a trial version of MonoDroid and I know that you can't deploy to your device with this version, but is there any other way of getting it to run on your phone? Does anyone know?

Comment: Surely to run it on your phone you have to deploy it first. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Even if you can get the package and its dependencies onto the phone by other means, the app will just crash. Buy it, or use the emulator.